# How to use MLT Framework through command line?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, command, mlt

I am new with video editing. I want to use the MLT framework through command line in order to edit thousands of video.
I am unable to install the framework. Can anyone help me with the installation process?

Comment: It would help greatly to mention what operating system you're using, and what have you tried already to install it!

Comment: I am using mac as of now.

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu or Debian based linux distros:

```
# sudo apt-get install melt
```

Fedora 22 or newer:

```
# dnf install melt
```

Windows:
Download the Shotcut Windows build here:
https://www.shotcut.org/download/
This installation comes with a Windows cross compile of melt.
To run it, you can open a terminal and call:

```
c:\Program Files\Shotcut\qmelt.exe
```

Mac:

Option 1 - install via homebrew:

```
# brew install mlt
```

Option 2 - install Shotcut and use the incuded melt script

```
https://shotcut.org/download/
```

Comment: Hi, I am using mac. I tried installing melt through terminal but its not woring

Comment: How do you install this on CentOS using yum?